Does $P(A|B)=P(A|B')$ prove $A$ and $B$ are independent events?
I'm currently in AP Statistics, and that formula seems intuitively right but my teacher can't find it acknowledged in any rubrics. I'm also curious if the inverse is true - that is, if $P(A|B)\neq P(A|B')$, does that prove $A$ and $B$ are not independent events?
The formula that is taught in the AP curriculum is that if $P(A|B)=P(A)$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent. From this, I conclude that $P(A|B')$ must also equal $P(A)$, because $P(A)$ would be the probability of $A$ in the entire sample space $(B\cup B')$, and therefore $P(A|B)=P(A|B')$ through the transitive property. Any help is appreciated; my teacher and I have been discussing this for the past few days.

$P(A\mid B)≠P(A\mid B')$ proves $A$ and $B$ are not independent events when both $P(B)>0$ and $P(B')>0$.  Otherwise you get the difficulties of conditioning on events of probability $0$.

An informal response is (in general) YES to the questions that you asked.  The mathematical foundation of whether $~A~$ and $~B~$ are independent events is whether the probability of event $~A~$ occurring has been affected by whether the event $~B~$ has occurred.  Clearly, event $~A~$ has been so affected if and only if $~p(A|B) \neq p(A|\neg B).~$ As indicated by the comment of Henry, I am assuming that $~P(B) > 0, ~P(\neg B) > 0.$

Let $p_{AB}=\mathbb P(A\cap B)$, $p_A=\mathbb P(A)$, $p_B=\mathbb P(B)$. Using $\mathbb P(A\cap B)+\mathbb P(A\cap B')=p_A$ and the definition of conditional probabilities, the equality $\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\mathbb P(A\mid B')$ translates as
$$
\frac{p_{AB}}{p_B}=\frac{p_A-p_{AB}}{1-p_B}.
$$
Multiplying on both sides by $p_B(1-p_B)$ gives
$$
p_{AB}(1-p_B)=p_B(p_A-p_{AB})
$$
from which independence between $A$ and $B$ follows.
